# Store procedure returns Error converting data type varchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Tags: python, sql-server, django, stored-procedures, django-views

I am trying to use stored procedure to do CRUD operations but while updating i am getting the error `Error converting data type varchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')`. I wrote a function to return null strings to an integer and return it and it seems to work fine (I printed the result) but I get error.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
USE [testenr]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateJobPost]
    @id int = Null,
    @TopicName nvarchar(300) = NULL,
    @UpdatedDate datetime2(7) = NULL,
    @IsActive bit = 0,
    @IsClose bit = 1,
    @ForceCloseReason nvarchar(3999) = NULL,
    @IsNotification bit = 0,
    @SMSText nvarchar(150) = NULL,
    @WhatsAppText nvarchar(1000) = NULL,
    @Category_id int = NULL,
    @CloseBy_id int = NULL,
    @ForceCloseCategory_id int = NULL,
    @SubCategory_id int = NULL,
    @User_id int = NULL
     
AS
UPDATE [dbo].[accounts_topiclist]
   SET     [TopicName]=@TopicName,
           [UpdatedDate]=@UpdatedDate,
           [IsActive]=@IsActive,
           [IsClose]=@IsClose,
           [ForceCloseReason]=@ForceCloseReason,
           [IsNotification]=@IsNotification,
           [SMSText]=@SMSText,
           [WhatsAppText]=@WhatsAppText,
           [Category_id]=Category_id,
           [CloseBy_id]=@CloseBy_id,
           [ForceCloseCategory_id]=@ForceCloseCategory_id,
           [SubCategory_id]=@SubCategory_id,
           [User_id]=@User_id
WHERE id = @id
GO
```

Here is the view:

```
def post(self, request, pk):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            topicname = request.POST['TopicName']
            category_id = AllProcedures.empty(request.POST['Category'])
            sub_Category = AllProcedures.empty(request.POST['SubCategory'])
            isActive = request.POST.get('IsActive')
            active = AllProcedures.boolcheck(isActive)
            isClose = request.POST.get('IsClose')
            close = AllProcedures.boolcheck(isClose)
            closed_by = AllProcedures.empty(request.POST['CloseBy'])
            closereason = request.POST['ForceCloseReason']
            CLosedCategory = AllProcedures.empty(request.POST['ForceCloseCategory'])
            isNotify = request.POST.get('IsNotification')
            notify = AllProcedures.boolcheck(isNotify)
            sms = request.POST['SMSText']
            wap = request.POST['WhatsAppText']
            li = [request.user.email, request.user.City, pk, topicname, category_id, sub_Category, active, close, closed_by, closereason, CLosedCategory, notify, sms, wap]
            print(li)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"EXEC dbo.updateJobPost @id='{pk}', @TopicName='{topicname}', @UpdatedDate='{datetime.datetime.now()}', @IsActive='{active}', @IsClose='{close}', @ForceCloseReason='{closereason}', @IsNotification='{notify}', @SMSText='{sms}', @Category_id='{category_id}', @CloseBy_id='{closed_by}', @ForceCloseCategory_id='{CLosedCategory}', @SubCategory_id='{sub_Category}', @User_id='{request.user.email}'")
            return redirect('/alljobs')
```

This is the li I am trying to print:

```
['dummy@gmail.com', 'India', 5, '325453354', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, '', 0, 1, '', '']
```

There are a few fields where the form returns empty strings, I have written this function to convert the type.

```
@staticmethod
    def empty(var):
        if var == '':
            return 0
        else: 
            return int(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be any of the strings you are passing to int parameters, but this one

```
 @User_id='{request.user.email}'")
```

is almost certianly wrong since

```
 @User_id int = NULL
```

It is a *much* better and safer practice to use parameters in your SQL instead of string interpolation.  See example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#insert-a-row), so something like:

```
cursor.execute(f"EXEC dbo.updateJobPost @id=?, @TopicName=?, @UpdatedDate=?, @IsActive=?, @IsClose=?, @ForceCloseReason=?, @IsNotification=?, @SMSText=?, @Category_id=?, @CloseBy_id=?, @ForceCloseCategory_id=?, @SubCategory_id=?, @User_id=?",     pk,topicname,datetime.datetime.now(),active,close,closereason,notify,sms,category_id,closed_by,CLosedCategory,sub_Category,request.user.email)
```